# variable won't be changed from a text document in python

Tags: python, variables

I've got a computing project to do for school where a text document is read and the person who spent the most time excercising on each intensity.When it is run the variables don't change and it is still showing that the top score is 0, if anyone could help show me where i've gone wrong that would be great,

thanks!

The text document looks like this:

```
NeQua,High,Running,5,Swimming,40,Aerobics,40,Football,20,Tennis,10
ImKol,Moderate,Walking,40,Hiking,0,Cleaning,40,Skateboarding,30,Basketball,20
YoTri,Moderate,Walking,20,Hiking,30,Cleaning,40,Skateboarding,20,Basketball,40
RoDen,High,Running,20,Swimming,20,Aerobics,40,Football,30,Tennis,50

etc.
```

---

```
moderate_top_player = ""
high_top_player = ""
moderate_top_score = 0
high_top_score = 0


# open file, with will automatically close it for you
with open("text_documents/clientRecords.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        ID,intensity,activity_1,time_1,activity_2,time_2,activity_3,time_3,activity_4,time_4,activity_5,time_5 = line.split(",")
        client_score = int(time_1) + int(time_2) + int(time_3) + int(time_4) + int(time_5)
        if intensity == "high" and  client_score > high_top_score:
            high_top_score = int(client_score)
            high_top_player = str(ID)

        elif intensity == "moderate" and  client_score > moderate_top_score:
            moderate_top_score = client_score
            moderate_top_player = ID
```

print(moderate_top_player,"worked",moderate_top_score,"minutes on moderate intensity")
print(high_top_player,"worked",high_top_score,"minutes on high intensity")

Comment: What is this line ? ID,intensity,activity_1,time_1,activity_2,time_2,activity_3,time_3,activity_4,time_4,activity_5,time_5 = line.split(",")
        client_score = int(time_1) + int(time_2) + int(time_3) + int(time_4) + int(time_5)

Comment: is `ID` always a string or always an int? The code does not seem to be coherent

Answer (score 3):

I've taken the liberty of renaming some of your variables and using the `csv` module from the Python standard library to read in the text file instead of manually splitting lines based on commas.

That said, the problem is pretty straight forward to fix. Your data set `clientRecords.txt` uses capitalized strings for `intensity` (e.g. `High`, `Moderate`) but in your conditional you are comparing against lowercase strings. `High` == `high` returns `False` so the body of the `if` and the `elif` blocks are never executed.

```
import csv

moderate_top_player = ""
high_top_player = ""
moderate_top_score = 0
high_top_score = 0

with open('text_documents/clientRecords.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        player_id, intensity, a1, t1, a2, t2, a3, t3, a4, t4, a5, t5 = row
        client_score = int(t1) + int(t2) + int(t3) + int(t4) + int(t5)
        intensity = intensity.lower()
        if intensity == 'high' and client_score > high_top_score:
            high_top_score = client_score
            high_top_player = player_id
        elif intensity == 'moderate' and client_score > moderate_top_score:
            moderate_top_score = client_score
            moderate_top_player = player_id

print moderate_top_player, moderate_top_score
print high_top_player, high_top_score
```

The important line:

```
intensity = intensity.lower()
```

Alternatively, instead of converting the read-in `intensity` to lower case, you could change your `if` statements to test against `High` instead of `high` and `Moderate` instead of `moderate`. Either way will do.

Comment: Thank you, that was such a stupid mistake! I feel like an idiot for not spotting it!

Comment: @iddyman Don't worry, it's very common when you are writing programs - even when you have been doing it for a long time.